# in jQuery, why is the value of "this" when querying 'meta[name]' different from 'meta[http-equiv]' different?

Tags: javascript, jquery, meta-tags, jquery-filter

Given:

```
<meta name="someKindOfId" value="asdf" />
<meta http-equiv="Set-Cookie" content="cookie_value1" />
```

and

```
var meta1 = $('meta[name]').filter(function() {
    console.log(this['name']);
});

var meta2 = $('meta[http-equiv]').filter(function() {
    console.log(this['http-equiv']);
});
```

The first `console.log` outputs `someKindOfId` (correct).

But the second `console.log` outputs `undefined` twice, instead of `Set-Cookie`?

Why is this so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `name` is a property of dom element object where are `http-equiv` is not, it is an attribute value which is not copied as a property so try

```
var meta2 = $('meta[http-equiv]').filter(function() {
    console.log($(this).attr('http-equiv'));
});
```

Attributes like `name`, `id`, `value` has corresponding property matches in the dom element reference, so those values will get copied to the properties of the dom element reference and `this` inside the filter refers to the dom element

Comment: @Obay the solution would work.. might be there is something wrong in my explanation... since the downvoter didn't leave any comment your guess is as good as mine...

Comment: @Obay any way you can wait for some other answer which might point out what is wrong with this one

Comment: It sort of works. Now the output is `someKindOfId`, `content-type`, `Set-Cookie`. Where is the `content-type` is coming from?

Comment: @Obay it look like you have a meta element with name `content-type`??